# Bash script: check a list of commands

Tags: bash, scripting

I have a bash script that launches a `ps` command with a list of commands like this:

```
comando="ps -o pid,pcpu,cmd -C \"$2\""
```

$2 must be a variable in this form: `command1` or `command1 command2 command3 ... commandn`

How can i check this variable in order to avoid errors? I need a control (with an if) to check the pattern.

EDIT: `ps` can be called in this way:

`ps -o pid,pcpu,cmd -C "command1 command2 ... commandn"`. If someone calls this bash script as `script.sh -C "   command1 command2"`, the ps command returns "IMPROPER LIST". I want to avoid the `ps` error and echo my error before launching `ps` command.

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: Yeah! Do this change something? :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should [avoid putting commands in variables](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

If spaces are what are tripping you up, you can strip them like this:

```
ps -o pid,pcpu,cmd -C ${2// }
```

That will strip *all* spaces though, so if any of your command strings contain spaces it will ruin them. This will strip leading and trailing spaces and spaces on either side of commas:

```
commands=${2/# }          # leading space
commands=${command/% }    # trailing space
commands=${command/, /,}  # spaces after commas
commands=${command/ ,/,}  # spaces before commas
ps -o pid,pcpu,cmd -C "$commands"
```

If you want to return an error instead of sanitizing and running the input, just do that space removal or other sanitizing and check to see if the result is equal to the input. If they're not then output an error.

Comment: perfect, i can sanitize the command without giving any error! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It could work with a for loop

```
arguments="command1 command2 command3 command4 command5"
for arg in $arguments
do
    ps -o pid,pcpu,cmd -C $arg
done
```

results:

```
ps -o pid,pcpu,cmd -C command1
ps -o pid,pcpu,cmd -C command2
ps -o pid,pcpu,cmd -C command3
ps -o pid,pcpu,cmd -C command4
ps -o pid,pcpu,cmd -C command5
```

Perhaps could you give a better real example of how it should work what are you expecting ... it doesnt look too clear to me.

---

To call it from the command line the way i explainned in the comment just use `$*` to catch all the arguments passed.

```
for arg in $*
do
    ps -o pid,pcpu,cmd -C $arg
done
```

then call it like this:

```
./test.sh command1 command2 command3 command4 command5 command6
```

and it will run the ps command with each argument.

Comment: PS can be called in this way:

ps -o pid,pcpu,cmd -C "command1 command2 ... commandn". If someone call this bash script as script.sh -C "   command1 command2", the ps command returns "IMPROPER LIST". I want to avoid the PS error and echo a my error before lunching ps command. Is it clear? :D

Comment: so what you really want is to be able to parse arguments to your test.sh that will be used on the -C option of your ps command, for example: test.sh command1 command2 command3 and they will run as the above output is that correct ?

Comment: see the answer for updates of the above comment.